# address sanitizer sometimes misses heap-use-after-free

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

Keeping a pointer on an element of a vector which is resized and dereferencing it afterwards
is undefined behavior.

When testing this bad practice on the following program with a `std::vector<int>` (with `#if 0`),
the address sanitizer correctly reports a heap-use-after-free error.

```
$ ./prog
capa: 8
v[0]: 0x603000000010 <1000>
p: 0x603000000010 <1000>
capa: 16
v[0]: 0x6060000000e0 <1000>
=================================================================
==23068==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000010
```

But when trying the same experiment with `std::vector<std::string>` (with `#if 1`),
the address sanitizer does not report anything, which leads to using a destroyed string
(probably moved-from during the resize) through the pointer!

```
$ ./prog
capa: 8
v[0]: 0x611000000040 <1000>
p: 0x611000000040 <1000>
capa: 16
v[0]: 0x615000000080 <1000>
p: 0x611000000040 <>
```

My question: why does not the address sanitizer report the error in this second case?
edit: valgrind reports the error.

I tested the following program on GNU/Linux x86_64 (Archlinux) with g++ 9.2.0 and clang++ 9.0.0.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog prog.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#if 1
# include <string>
  inline auto make_elem(int n) { return std::to_string(n); }
#else
  inline auto make_elem(int n) { return n; }
#endif

using elem_t = decltype(make_elem(0));

inline
void
fill(std::vector<elem_t> &v,
     int sz)
{
  v.resize(std::size_t(sz));
  for(auto i=0; i<sz; ++i)
  {
    v[i]=make_elem(1000+i);
  }
}

inline
void
show(const std::vector<elem_t> &v,
     const elem_t *p)
{
  std::cout << "capa: " << v.capacity() << '\n';
  std::cout << "v[0]: " << &v[0] << " <" << v[0] << ">\n";
  std::cout << "p: " << p << " <" << *p << ">\n"; // <-- possible invalid pointer here
}

int
main()
{
  constexpr auto sz=8;
  auto v=std::vector<elem_t>{};
  fill(v, sz);
  const auto *p=data(v);
  show(v, p);
  fill(v, 2*sz);
  show(v, p);
  return 0;
}
```

I've also filed [upstream bug](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1164) about this.

Comment: Did you let Valgrind have a go at your code?

Comment: @tadman yes, and it correctly reports the use-after-free bug (it is indeed present in my code). But I don't understand why the address-sanitizer does not (but does with a vector of int).

Comment: The compiler builtins are rarely as good as a special-purpose tool like Valgrind.

Comment: You're assuming that `std::vector::resize()` causes all pointers to elements of the vector to become invalid. However, `resize()` is not required to do reallocation, so there is no guarantee that `p` becomes invalid after the second call of `fill()`.    The circumstances in which reallocation occurs may also be affected by the size of the vector element (`sizeof(int)` versus `sizeof(std::string)`), compilation settings (optimisation, etc), .....    So it is not actually unreasonable that memory checking tools will not reliably detect every instance where `p` is *potentially* invalidated.

Comment: @Peter That's why the examples print `&v[0]` as well as `p` (and capacity); we see that reallocation did occur (and valgrind detects the error, so it is present). The compilation settings are given (`-O0`) and are the same in the two cases. The first thing I tried was to play with the size of the allocation but it does not change anything.

Comment: @tadman "The compiler builtins are rarely as good" - Valgrind lacks information about container's capacity (unless you use Valgrind-instrumented STL which GNU and libc++ are not due to performance issues) so it can't report STL overflows in many cases. Asan can do this under `-D_GLIBCXX_SANITIZE_STD_ALLOCATOR=1`.

Comment: @yugr There are some very neat features in the compiler itself, but I don't know if you can do it with compiler alone, you sort of need Valgrind too for other things.

Comment: @tadman Actually I think both Asan and Valgrind need support from STL to support proper container overflows (which is hidden under macro and calls Asan's `__asan_poison_memory` or Valgrind's `VALGRIND_MEM_DEFINED`, etc.). So I take my words back - both Valgrind and Asan have equal opportunities (but Asan already has support in libc++ and libstdc++).

Comment: I tried the above program with the indicated compile options, and the address sanitizer *does* report the bug in new versions of asan. Fedora 29, gcc 8.1.1, libasan-9.2.1-1.fc32.3.x86_64:
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:912 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented on github issue, but the short answer is that due to the way `libstdc++.so.6` splits certain common template instantiations, such as

```
basic_ostream<...>::operator<<(basic_ostream<...>&, const std::string &);
```

and instantiates them only once inside `libstdc++.so.6`, and because `libstdc++.so.6` itself is not asan-instrumented, all that instrumented code can see is that you are passing a dangling pointer into an external function. It doesn't know what the external function will do with this pointer, and so can't report the error.

The problem does *not* reproduce with `clang++ ... -stdlib=libc++` (dangling access is properly reported).